# How to make IndexPath rawRepresentable?

Tags: swift, xcode, indexpath

I am trying to refactor code and create an enum class to hold indexPath of table view cells.

I would like to make the code works this way:

```
enum TableViewCell: IndexPath {
     case shopImageView = [0,0]
     case selectShopImageButton = [0,1]
}
```

But the compiler says indexPath is not rawRepresentable:

> 'TableViewCell' declares raw type 'IndexPath', but does not conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized
>
> Raw value for enum case must be a literal

How can I make indexPath rawRepresentable? The code currently works like this and I would like to improve it.

```
enum TableViewCell {
    case shopImageView
    case selectShopImageButton
    case shopNameLocal
    case shopNameEN
    case addressLocal
    case addressEN
    case selectAddressButton
    case openingHours
    case datePickers
    case phone
    case email
    case uploadShopFormButton
    
    var indexPath: IndexPath {
        switch self {
        case .shopImageView:         return [0,0]
        case .selectShopImageButton: return [0,1]
        case .shopNameLocal:         return [0,2]
        case .shopNameEN:            return [0,3]
        case .addressLocal:          return [0,4]
        case .addressEN:             return [0,5]
        case .selectAddressButton:   return [0,6]
        case .openingHours:          return [0,7]
        case .datePickers:           return [0,8]
        case .phone:                 return [0,9]
        case .email:                 return [0,10]
        case .uploadShopFormButton:  return [0,11]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of using hard coded `TableView` `IndexPath`'s is to use an `enum` with static properties.  The benefit of doing this is that if you reference the `IndexPath`'s in various `TableView` delegate methods, and you need to change the `IndexPath` references, then you only have to change them once in the enum.

```
 private enum TableIndex {
    // Section 0: Information
    static let information =        IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    // Section 1: Preferences
    static let notifications =      IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
    static let units =              IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)
    static let hapticFeedback =     IndexPath(row: 2, section: 1)
    // Section 2: Links
    static let leaveReview =        IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2)
    static let support =            IndexPath(row: 1, section: 2)
    static let privacyPolicy =      IndexPath(row: 2, section: 2)
    static let disclaimer =         IndexPath(row: 3, section: 2)
}
```

and you can then reference them like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath {
    case TableIndex.information:
        // do something
    case TableIndex.notifications:
        // do something
    case TableIndex.units:
        // do something

        // etc

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways but not necessarily better, anyways you can cut down the code to this.

```
enum TableViewCell: Int  {
    case shopImageView = 0
    case selectShopImageButton = 1
    case shopNameLocal = 2
    case shopNameEN = 3
    case addressLocal
    case addressEN
    case selectAddressButton
    case openingHours
    case datePickers
    case phone
    case email
    case uploadShopFormButton
    
    var indexPath: IndexPath {
        return [0, self.rawValue]
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind it is also depending on how are you using them, like where and how are you passing the arguments.

One of the ways .

```
extension IndexPath {
     init(using type: TableViewCell) {
        self.init(row: type.rawValue, section: 0)
    }
}

let indexPath = IndexPath(using: .shopNameEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension IndexPath : RawRepresentable {
    public init?(rawValue: (Int, Int)) {
        self.init(row: rawValue.0, section: rawValue.1)
    }
    public var rawValue: (Int, Int) {
        (self.row, self.section)
    }
}

// We can't use array literal for raw value of an enum, but we can use `String` literal instead.
extension IndexPath: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public init(stringLiteral: StringLiteralType) {
        let a = stringLiteral.split(separator: ",")
        if let row = Int(a[0]), let section = Int(a[1]) {
             self.init(row: row, section: section)
        } else {
            self.init(row: 0, section: 0)
        }
    }
}
// We can use array literals to initialize `IndexPath` but not to define an enum case.
enum TableViewCell: IndexPath {
     case shopImageView = "0,0" // `String` literal
     case selectShopImageButton = "0,1" // `String` literal
}

print(TableViewCell.selectShopImageButton.rawValue)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to fix the compiler errors in the question. Can IndexPath be used as the raw value of an enum with this extension?

Comment: Yes, but raw values also must be expressible by `String` or number. I' ve updated the answer. Try it in playground, @pkamb .